# JRE 7 Eclipse & sqlite3 on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, macos, sqlite

I am trying to complete a program for my Java class final exam.
I am required to use sqlite3 for database purposes.  The instructor has included instructions on how to insert the sqlite.jar file into the program folder of Eclipse. Using this extension for Windows:copy sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar to this location C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext
I can't find any results on how to do this on a mac.
I am running OSX 10.10

Thanks for any answers.

-Brandon

Answer (score 0):

There is some useful info here: https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/qa/qa1170/_index.html

```
The /Library/Java/Extensions directory can be used for additional jar files or JNI libraries that need to be placed on the system classpath
```

and

```
~/Library/Java/Extensions directory can be used for user-level installation of support libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coping it to ext/, try this:

Right click your project in eclipse, then
Properties>Java Build Path> Libraries > click Add external JAR